# Get .csv-file with Python from url

Tags: python, file, csv, download

I'm trying to get a .csv-file from a url with Python. When I use the url in a browser I get the .csv-file downloaded but when I'm using this script I'm only getting html-code.

```
__file_url__ = "http://myurl.com/?export"
data = urllib2.urlopen(__file_url__)
        for line in data:
            print(line)
```

Thanx for all help!

Comment: This is a server-side issue. Your server varies responses by something, and we don't know what by. It could be cookies, it could be the `User-Agent` header, it could be the phase of the moon. This is *not* a Python-specific issue.

Comment: Oh, okey.. well, that would explain the dynamic file-naming-thingy. So there's no way I could receive this file using python?

Comment: You probably can, but you need to figure out what magic combination of headers the server varies on. I'd start playing with the headers your browser sends, and seeing which one added to the Python request make a difference.

Comment: Okey, I'll try that out, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am super stupid. It's required to be logged in to download this. And ofcourse, when making the request from Python I was not logged in. So, I needed to use the session from the request lib to first post a login formular and then ask for the file again and wiola - there's my file.

```
from requests import session
s = session()
s.post('http://myurl.com/login', data = { 'username': 'myusername', 'password': 'mypassword' })
download = s.get('http://myurl.com/?export')
```